# How to use variables for Manifest.permission names in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to use variables for permission names in Kotlin.
Specifically, in the code below, I want $Permission to subsutitute object.

```
checkPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");

fun checkPermission(PermissionString:String): Boolean {
    val Permission = (Make PermissionString an object somehow)
    return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        Context,
        Permission
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}
```

Appreciate any responses. Thanks!

Comment: A String already is an object. And the parameter you need to pass should be a String, not just an arbitrary object, but your `PermissionString` parameter above already is a String.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!
I solved the problem by using android.permission.ANY_PERMISSION instead of Manifest.permission.ANY_PERMISSION. I am not very familiar with Kotlin, so thanks to you for your very helpful input!